# Tool which converts Python2.7 code to Python3 compatible code

Tags: python

I have a huge code base which supports Python 2.7.

Now I search a tool which helps me to transform the source code to source code which works on Python 2.7 and Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [futurize](http://python-future.org/automatic_conversion.html) script passes Python 2 code through all the appropriate fixers to turn it into valid Python 3 code, and then adds `__future__` and future package imports to re-enable compatibility with Python2.

Answer (score 2):

Python comes with a tool called [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/2to3.html), which is specifically designed for converting Python 2 to Python 3.

Usually, most of the the converted code works in Python 2.7 as well, in particular after imports from `__future__`.
In this case, most of the incompatabilities can be handled on a per-case basis.
In my experience, a main exception from this is Unicode string handling, but if you are dealing with that, you want to get completely rid of Python 2 as quickly as possible anyway.

Comment: The result should be code which runs on both: Python2.7 and Python3.